# Master field editable on VF page (reparent detail to new master)

Tags: apex, custom-button, master-detail, visualforce

I am trying to create a standard clone button type functionality for a custom object which has a master detail relationship with Account and lookup with Contact. On click on the custom button a vf page is loaded. In this vf page can we make the Account field as editable? Right now its coming as read only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sharing setting for this Account field is : Read/Write: Allows users with at least Read/Write access to the Master record to create, edit, or delete related Detail records.

Comment: Are you using <apex:inputfield> on VF page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution. On the field we have this option Reparentable Master Detail. That needs to be checked. And then with the help of field sets the field can be displayed in editable mode on the VF page.